# How does Python support randomly chosen variable names?

Tags: python, flask

In Flask there is the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="title">
  Welcome,{{ anyweirdname }}!
</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

You can render this HTML file using:

```
render_template('text.html', anyweirdname = "foo")
```

How can such syntatic sugar be implemented using Python? In other words, how can the computer know, that at `{{ anyweirdname }}` has to be replaced using `anyweirdname = "foo"`

Obviously this is not possible in languages like C, because C does not change its compilation by using another variable name. One would presume that the code used with other variable names - basically an isomorphism - would be indifferent, but it is obviously not.

Comment: Are you asking about keyword arguments, or the templating itself (which is [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) not just Python)?

Comment: I wonder how I could reproduce this functionality.

Comment: You mean write your own template language for Python? Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: Given a text file full of names seperated by " ". How can I substitute the names with their values specified in a variable which is named exactly the same.

So in the case above, the output would be "Welcome, foo"

Comment: You can write your own templating language, or just use an existing one like Jinja. It's not clear why you think there's "syntactic sugar", the templating is *not* Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a string where you can you can substitute variable names directly.

This can be done in Python 3.0+ using f-strings:

```
anyweirdname = 'foo'
print(f"Hello, {anyweirdname}")
```

Basically, you write `f` in front of the string where you want a variable substituted.
If this indeed is what you asked, you can find more information in [this article](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python).

Comment: f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6, not 3.0 also see https://github.com/jugmac00/python-version-cheat-sheet